# Insert reference to page number in Microsoft Publisher 2010

Tags: ms-office, ms-publisher

I am new to MS Publisher 2010, and I am trying to add a "dynamic" reference to a specific page. Ideally, the visualized text should be something like:

```
...see the example on page XXX
```

I would like to make the XXX part visualize the page number of the page I am referring to. I saw that you can place bookmarks in the document, and create hyperlinks to those bookmarks, but so far I could not manage to visualize the page number tied to a bookmark.

To make another example, I would like the equivalent of this Latex expression:

```
...see the example on page~\pageref{reference-to-XXX}
```

Would it be possible to obtain this effect in Publisher 2010, maybe using a VB script? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-office_other/how-do-i-hyperlink-specific-text-within-the-same/598cfd98-6217-4eac-9ac9-969477c46401?auth=1

> "This is fairly easy with Pub 2007. Just Insert > bookmark and drag that icon to where you want the link to go. Then select the text >insert hyperlink > place in this document and choose the bookmark that you just created. The only time I have had problems is if the page is not long enough below the bookmark...and there are workarounds.
>   http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/publisher-help/create-a-hyperlink-HP010203490.aspx
>   DavidF"

Let me know if this helps or if you for some reason need to do it in VBA

Edit:
It is fairly easy to write a macro to refresh links to pages, but links to bookmarks seem to be poorly supported by the object model, unless I've overlooked something. My solution consists of two parts.

First of all, links that should be refreshed are recognised by their display text starting with "page " (LIKE "page *"). The refresh macro simply recognizes those links and changes their display text to page X. However, this doesn't work for links to bookmarks, which in the object model seem to behave like links to pages, except the pageID they refer to does not exist. I spent quite a while trying to figure out what the relationship might be between this non-existent hyperlink and the bookmark, but to no avail. Instead I've created a workaround in which you manually link the hyperlink and the bookmark with a tag object (creating a tag for the bookmark with the value of the non-existent page ID of the hyperlink).

**Instructions for normal links to pages**

1. Create a hyperlink to a page. The text of it must begin with ”page ”
   (otherwise RefreshReferenceLinks must be edited)
2. Run C_RefreshReferenceLinks to refresh to check that it worked

**Instructions for links to bookmarks (tagging workaround)**

1. Create a bookmark (Insert -> Bookmark)
2. Create a hyperlink to the Bookmark
3. Select the hyperlink and run A_GetPageIdOfHyperlink
4. Select the bookmark and run B_TagBookmarkWithPageId
5. Run C_RefreshReferenceLinks to refresh to check that it worked

You can download my example project containing example content, instructions, and the macros below here: http://www.filedropper.com/showdownload.php/pageandbookmarklinks (it will probably give you a security warning because it contains macros)

**Full source**

```
Public Const tagName = "BookmarkPageId"

Sub A_GetPageIdOfHyperlink()
    Dim oHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Set oHyperlink = ActiveDocument.Selection.TextRange.Hyperlinks(1)
    CopyText oHyperlink.pageId
    MsgBox oHyperlink.pageId & " copied to clipboard as text"
End Sub

Sub B_TagBookmarkWithPageId()
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Set oShape = ActiveDocument.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    If IsBookmark(oShape) Then
        If TagExists(oShape.Tags, tagName) Then
            oShape.Tags(tagName).Delete
        End If

        Dim txt As String
        txt = Trim(GetClipBoardText())
        Debug.Print "Ssdsd:" & txt

        Dim newTag As Tag
        Set newTag = oShape.Tags.Add(tagName, txt)

        MsgBox "Tagged as " & tagName & " = '" & txt & "'"
    Else
        MsgBox "Not a bookmark"
    End If


End Sub


Sub C_RefreshReferenceLinks()
    Dim oPage As Page
    Dim oShape As Shape

     For Each oPage In ActiveDocument.Pages
        For Each oShape In oPage.Shapes
          RefreshInShape oShape
        Next oShape
    Next oPage

    For Each oPage In ActiveDocument.MasterPages
        For Each oShape In oPage.Shapes
          RefreshInShape oShape
        Next oShape
    Next oPage

    For Each oShape In ActiveDocument.ScratchArea.Shapes
        RefreshInShape oShape
    Next oShape

End Sub

Function RefreshInShape(oShape As Shape)
    Dim cHyperlinks As Hyperlinks
    Dim oHyperlink As Hyperlink

    If oShape.HasTextFrame = False Then Exit Function

    Set cHyperlinks = oShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Hyperlinks

    For i = 1 To cHyperlinks.Count

        Set oHyperlink = cHyperlinks(i)

        If oHyperlink.TargetType = pbHlinkTargetTypePageID Then

            If oHyperlink.TextToDisplay Like "page *" Then
                oHyperlink.TextToDisplay = "page " & GetPageNumberByPageId(oHyperlink.pageId)
            End If

        End If

    Next i
End Function

Function GetPageNumberByPageId(pageId)
    Dim oPage As Page
    Dim oShape As Shape
    Dim oTag As Tag

    For Each oPage In ActiveDocument.Pages

        If CLng(oPage.pageId) = CLng(pageId) Then
            GetPageNumberByPageId = oPage.PageNumber
            Exit Function
        End If

    Next oPage

    For Each oPage In ActiveDocument.Pages
        For Each oShape In oPage.Shapes
            If TagExists(oShape.Tags, tagName) Then
                Set oTag = oShape.Tags(tagName)
                If CStr(oTag.Value) = CStr(pageId) Then
                    GetPageNumberByPageId = oPage.PageNumber
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        Next oShape
    Next oPage

    GetPageNumberByPageId = "[ERROR]"

End Function


Function IsBookmark(oShape As Shape)
    IsBookmark = False
    If oShape.Type = pbWebHTMLFragment And oShape.AutoShapeType = msoShapeMixed Then
        IsBookmark = True
    End If
End Function

Function TagExists(collection As Tags, itemName As String) As Boolean
    TagExists = False
    Dim oTag As Tag
    For Each oTag In collection
        If oTag.Name = itemName Then
        TagExists = True
        Exit For
        End If
    Next oTag
End Function

Function GetParentOfType(obj As Object, sTypeName As String)
    Do Until TypeName(GetParentOfType) = "Page"
        Set GetParentOfType = obj.Parent
    Loop
End Function


Sub CopyText(Text As String)
    'VBA Macro using late binding to copy text to clipboard.
    'By Justin Kay, 8/15/2014
    'Thanks to http://akihitoyamashiro.com/en/VBA/LateBindingDataObject.htm
    Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
    MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetClipBoardText() As String
   Set DataObj = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

   On Error GoTo Whoa

   '~~> Get data from the clipboard.
   DataObj.GetFromClipboard

   '~~> Get clipboard contents
   GetClipBoardText = DataObj.GetText(1)


   Exit Function
Whoa:
   GetClipBoardText = ""
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but an hyperlink is not exactly what I wanted. I would like to insert a phrase like "see page 22 for an example" where the '22' is dynamically updated when the document changes. For example, if the example is moved to page 24, the phrase should update and read "see page 24 for an example".

Comment: Hi Alberto, please check if my new answer helps!

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out :-)